# log log regression model with normalised dependent variable

Tags: regression, predictive-models, prediction

I inherited some a regression code, which fits some log log model – simplified model:

$log{(Y)} = \beta_0+ \beta_1log{(X)}$

The training data Y values are normalized by dividing them by the maximum value of all Ys.

I am just wondering how this model could be used for predictions given unseen data. Should I simply exponentize the predicted value and multiply it by the training data's maximum value? Or would I multiply by the unseen data's maximum value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that the logarithm is a non-linear transformation so $\textrm{E}(\log(y))\neq \log(\mathrm{E}(y))$. Exponentize the prediction will get you $\mathrm{E}(y)$ in the latter case, but your model gives you the former. You can use a [smearing retransformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smearing_retransformation) to get an estimate of $\mathrm{E}(y)$.

Now it depends on whether you first divided the $y$ by the maximum and than took the logarithm or whether you first computed $\log(y)$ and than divided $\log(y)$ by its maximum.

Comment: y is divided by the maximum first and then logged ...

Comment: In that case you first apply the smearing retransformation and than multiply by the max.

Comment: Thanks - just curious - would you take the variance from the training dataset to perform the smearing retransformation?

Comment: The Wikipedia page is not very clear: the variance is the variance of the errors (a.k.a. mean squared error or standard error of the estimate squared).

Comment: How would this work with unseen data? Here I cannot determine the variance of the error as I do not know the 'truth'.

Comment: You never know the truth, so error does not refer to deviation from the truth. The error is the observed $y$ minus the predicted $y$.

Comment: Yeah but if I use the model against unseen data (i.e. to predict) I do not have the observed Ys (the 'truth') ...

Comment: The rmse is a parameter like any other, so you extract it directly from your model after you estimate it.